# OCamlのリスト探索

Tags: ocaml

```
let ls = [[1;2;3];[4;5;6];[7;8;9]];;
```

といったint listリストの中から、特定の値が入っているリストが欲しい時、どのような操作を行えば良いでしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

[`List`モジュール](http://ocaml.jp/refman/libref/List.html)にある関数のうち、条件を満たす要素のみ取り出す`filter`関数と、条件を満たす要素が少なくとも一つ存在するか調べる`exists`関数を使って次のように書くことができます。

```
(* 5を含むリストを探す例 *)
# List.(filter (fun l -> exists (fun x -> x = 5) l) ls);;
```